# ActiveModelSerializer not kicking in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, react-rails

I want to serialize the newly created resource in this action  :

```
def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.json { render json: @comment }
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: "Comment successfully created." }
      else

        format.html { render 'questions/show' }  
      end
    end 
  end
```

But `render json: @comment` is returning the full object although in my CommentSerializer I have :

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
end
```

I am creating the new resource via ajax :

```
handleSubmit: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/questions/" + this.props.question_id + "/comments",
            data: {comment: this.state},
            success: function(data){
                this.props.handleNewComment(data);
                this.setState(this.getInitialState);
            }
        });

    },
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can explicitly set the serializer when rendering JSON

change

```
 format.json { render json: @comment }
```

to

```
  format.json { render json: CommentSerializer.new(@comment) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing `contentType`, so add `contentType: "application/json"` to your ajax function.

Comment: The request is being sent just fine, the response is not being serialized, so this is not the cause.